# Positive lookbehind/lookahead RegEx VBA

Tags: regex, vba

I know that VBA does not support positive lookahead/lookbehind, so I need some advice with the problem below.

I want to replace all spaces only between single characters so that A B C becomes ABC but AB C stays AB C.

```
ObjRegex.Pattern = "((?<=\b\w)\s(?=\w\b))"
SampleString = ObjRegex.Replace(SampleString, vbNullString)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
ObjRegex.Pattern = "\b(\w)\s(?=\w)\b"
SampleString = ObjRegex.Replace(SampleString, "$1" & vbNullString)
```

The lookbehind can be turned into a capturing group and its consumed value can be restored (put back) into the result with the `$1` placeholder.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yE7LOY/1).

**Pattern details**

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(\w)` - Group 1 (referred to with `$1` placeholder from the replacement pattern): a word char
- `\s` - a whitespace
- `(?=\w)` - a positive lookahead that requires a word char immediately to the right of the current position
- `\b` - a word boundary